# Html audio player cannot get music from src url, on hosted server, but works perfectly well on localhost

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, mime-types, src

My Html audio player returns 404 error when I load the page on a hosting server. I don't know why this happens but when I click on the src url, it downloads the music which means the src is not the issue and I have checked the mime type on cpanel and everything is accurate.
But when it runs from localhost, I don't receive any error.

NOTE: The url is from YouTube music player API and connection to YouTube server is required before you can access it.

Amy hint that can solve this problem???

Comment: please show your relevant code

Comment: Do you have any specific reported errors in the *Network* tab of Developer Tools?